# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'openDatabase' of undefined - only from physical device

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, telerik

I am using SQLite plugin for cordova. I'm making a telerik mobile/kendo mobile app.  I use the telerik appBuilder windows client IDE. I clicked plugins and checked the SQLite plugin check box to make sure it is integrated with my app.

When running the app from the simulator within the telerik appBuilder IDE, the app works fine. But when I remote debug the app from my Android Nexus 5 or just try and use the app at all from the nexus 5, it stalls at the start. I can see in the remote debugger that it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'openDatabase' of undefined`  about the line marked "HERE" in this function:

```
app.openDb = function() {
   if (window.navigator.simulator === true) {
        // For debuging in simulator fallback to native SQL Lite
            console.log("Use built in SQLite");
            app.db = window.openDatabase("VCareMobileDB", "1.0", "Shopping List Demo", 200000);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Using SQLite Plugin DB");
            app.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("VCareMobileDB"); //HERE
    }
}
```

Why might this line trigger the error from a physical device and not from the telerik appbuilder simulator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different openDatabase API calls `window.openDatabase` and `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase`.

For `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase` you **need to** install the plugin.

For `window.openDatabase` you **do not** need to install any plugin.